# Are All Might and Midoriya equally strong when they use One for All 100%?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Even though Midoriya can't use One for All without breaking his body, if both Midoriya and All Might use One for All 100% in their primes, are they supposed to be equally strong? Does their particular body influence how much strong each one are or by having One for All they are about the same? Does the manga give some light about this?

Comment: Midoriya would be stronger. Because One For All stockpiles power and energy from previous users. The first One For All user couldn't beat All for One, but All Might was able to. This is a classic example of the power difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ero Sɘnnin stated OfA stockpiles however with the latest chapters of manga we have to consider one more thing.

Manga spoilers:

> In the latest chapters in his dream, Izuku sees the first user of OfA, brother of AfO user, and some event that happened at that era. However at the end first user of OfA talks with Izuku. That never happened to All Might and this is stated in anime and manga. After waking up his hands starts to glow. I think that was a power-up so he is definitely becoming stronger and will suppress All Might.

Not the mention of he calling himself "Greatest hero" in the first episode.

Comment: Too add on, the quirk is supposed to get stronger each time its passed on is it not?  So All Might's 100% is his plus all previous wielders, while Midoria's would be the same as All Mights plus his own, making it stronger.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no (or not yet).

In the training/test where All Might fought Midoriya and Bakugo, All Might punch(not One For All 100%) shockwave produced a much bigger destruction than all Mirodiya's punches(100% or not) up to date(in the Anime).

Comment: OP was considering their prime so saying not yet or talking about the power compression is not something OP seeks.

Comment: @JustPlain ah okay, didn't see the "in their primes" my bad. I think we can only speculate with limited information since Midoriya hasn't reach his prime yet.